# Greatest integer function and moebius function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation

I am able to get the moebius function and it's definition as such but I am not able to get the notation that divisor sum extended over the positive divisors of 'n' is [1/n] = 1, if n=1 or 0 if n>1. Can anyone please clarify this

Comment: you want to know why $\sum_{d | n} \mu(d) = \lfloor 1/n \rfloor = 1_{n= 1}$, it is because by definition $\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}, \frac{1}{\zeta(s)} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(n) n^{-s}$, multiplying the two you have the result

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I wanted to know. It's still not clear to me. Can it be illustrated by an example.

Comment: $(\sum_{m=1}^\infty a_m m^{-s})(\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k k^{-s}) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_m  b_k (mk)^{-s} $ $ = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s} \sum_{mk = n} a_m b_k = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s} \sum_{d | n} a_d b_{n/d}$. With $a_n = \mu_n$ and $b_n = 1$ you get  $1 = \frac{1}{\zeta(s)} \zeta(s) =\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s} \sum_{d | n} \mu_d$

Comment: I am not able to get this.

Comment: if you don't explain what you understand and what you don't, I can't help you

Comment: I am not able to get the idea/intuition behind the greatest integer function and how it is related to the divisor sum of the moebius function.

Comment: What I wrote $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s} \sum_{d | n} \mu_d = 1$ shows that $\sum_{d | n} \mu_d = 0$ if $n > 1$. Then check that $\lfloor 1/n \rfloor = 0$ if $n > 1$, and compare the value when $n = 1$.